# Will deleting a message prevent it from sending?

Tags: ipad, messages

I accidentally sent a message to the wrong person on my iPad air 2, so I quickly turned off wifi on my iPad. The message didn't send yet, but it doesn't say the not delivered thing. The loading bar still shows at the top of my screen. If I delete the message, will it prevent it from sending?

Comment: How do you know “it didn’t send yet?”  It may have been sent and you cut WiFi before the acknowledgement message was generated by the server(s).  Generally speaking, if it’s in your outbox, you can delete it and it won’t send.  If it’s not, consider it gone.

Comment: I know it didn't send because the loading bar is at the top right next to the person's name. It won't send because I tuend off Wifi.

Comment: Did you check you outbox?